# Log in using IAM database authentication failed in Google CloudSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I tried to use [Log in using IAM database authentication](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#log_in_with_automatic)
with service account. but failed

> Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user

I was totally stacled

## procedure

### 1. create postgreSQL

instance **test-auth**

and set flag

```
databaseFlags:
- name: cloudsql.iam_authentication
  value: on
```

### 2. create db

dbname: **db_hoge**

### 3. create service account

**sa-cloudsql@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com**
and add it as user. also, I added my own email ( which is the owner of this GCP project)
it looked added correctly.

> $  gcloud sql users list --instance test-auth

```
NAME                               HOST  TYPE                       PASSWORD_POLICY
postgres                                 CLOUD_IAM_USER
maiil@mydomain.co.jp                     CLOUD_IAM_USER
sa-cloudsql@myproject.iam                CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

### 4. running cloud sql proxy ( v 1.31.0)

> $ ./cloud_sql_proxy -version

```
Cloud SQL Auth proxy: 1.31.0+linux.amd64
```

> $ ./cloud_sql_proxy -enable_iam_login -instances=myproject:asia-northeast1:test-auth=tcp:127.0.0.1:5432

### 5. DB connection

### with service account -> failed

> psql "sslmode=disable dbname=db_hoge host=127.0.0.1 user=sa-cloudsql@myproject.iam"

```
 psql: error: FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user "sa-cloudsql@myproject.iam"
```

### with user (myself) -> success

> psql "sslmode=disable dbname=db_hoge host=127.0.0.1 user=maiil@mydomain.co.jp"

```
psql (12.11 (Ubuntu 12.11-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), server 14.2)
WARNING: psql major version 12, server major version 14.
         Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

db_hoge=>
```

## IAM role

- maiil@mydomain.co.jp => **owner**
- sa-cloudsql@myproject.iam => **roles/cloudsql.client** ,　**roles/cloudsql.instanceUser**

I sincerely ask someone's kindly help.

Thank you in advance

---

## update

following advice, I deployed app for testing connection on GKE

But now, I got error "FATAL: empty password returned by client".
When using IAM database authentication, we should not need password for that user.

I don't know it's because of App, GKE, IAM, or CloudSQL.

#### Deployment and App

Using sidecar, I runned cloudSQL proxy. and service-account for this pod has been binded google-service-account which has CloudSQL instance user & CloudSQL Client.

app.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: cloudproxy-test:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      - command:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy
        - -enable_iam_login
        - -instances=my-project:asia-northeast1:test-auth=tcp:5432
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.25.0
        name: cloudsql-proxy        
      serviceAccountName: ksa-workload-identity-binded     
---
```

I made app with go. for postgreSQL, use [dialers/postgres module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/tree/main/proxy).

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    _ "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/proxy/dialers/postgres"
)


func main() {

  engine := gin.Default()
  engine.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    if err := showRecords(ctx, "my-project:asia-northeast1:test-auth", "db_hoge", "sa-cloudsql@my-project.iam"); err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
      "How": "itwork",
    })
  })

  engine.Run(":8080")
}

func showRecords(ctx context.Context, dbAddress, dbName, dbUser string) error {
    dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", dbAddress, dbUser, dbName)

    fmt.Println(dsn)

    db, err := sql.Open("cloudsqlpostgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)    
        return err
    }
    defer db.Close()
    return nil
}
```

When I used default user `postgres` with password and remove **-enable_iam_login** option from sidecar command, I could connect with DB.
So Application itself seemed not wrong.

Comment: Where are you running the commands at step 5? The credentials need to be available for whatever IAM user you specify. It's possible you can log in because your credentials can be found

Comment: To use a service account to connect to the DB you would normally be running within gcp environment such as cloud run, cloud functions etc as the service account and pass the credentials as the password

Comment: @rossco Thank you for your comment. I tried it on my local environment, not GCP, It must be the reason

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out how to get this to connect from a non-GKE container? I'm trying exactly what you're trying from an instance inside GCP and can't figure out what the problem is. I created a similar thread on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191072/psql-error-fatal-cloud-sql-iam-service-account-authentication-failed-for-user

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 cases where you can recieve this message:

1. You didn't enable IAM database authentication on the Cloud SQL instance.

   ```
   $ docker compose exec app psql -h proxy -U myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam postgres
   psql: error: connection to server at "proxy" (172.20.0.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user "myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam"

   $ gcloud logging read "resource.type=cloudsql_database" --project=PROJECT_ID --limit=10
   ---
   ...
   textPayload: |-
     2023-08-31 23:34:40.377 UTC [1182]: [2-1] db=postgres,user=myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam DETAIL:  Cloud SQL IAM authentication not enabled
     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 21: "local   all           +cloudsqliamserviceaccount         cloudsql-iam-svc-acct"
   ---
   ...
   textPayload: '2023-08-31 23:34:40.377 UTC [1182]: [1-1] db=postgres,user=myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam
     FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user "myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam"'
   timestamp: '2023-08-31T23:34:40.377967Z'
   ---
   ...
   ```
2. You didn't grant the service account the Cloud SQL Instance User (`roles/cloudsql.instanceUser`) role.

   ```
   $ docker compose exec app psql -h proxy -U myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam postgres
   psql: error: connection to server at "proxy" (172.20.0.2), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user "myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam"

   $ gcloud logging read "resource.type=cloudsql_database" --project=PROJECT_ID --limit=10
   ---
   ...
   textPayload: |-
     2023-08-31 23:38:34.595 UTC [1279]: [2-1] db=postgres,user=myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam DETAIL:  Not authorized to access resource. Possibly missing permission cloudsql.instances.login on resource projects/PROJECT_ID/instances/myinstance.
     Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 21: "local   all           +cloudsqliamserviceaccount         cloudsql-iam-svc-acct"
   ---
   ...
   textPayload: '2023-08-31 23:38:34.595 UTC [1279]: [1-1] db=postgres,user=myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam
     FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user "myaccount@PROJECT_ID.iam"'
   ---
   ...
   ```

Considering this it's strange that you got the message, because it seems like you enabled IAM auth and granted the role. But maybe you didn't grant the role after all. Check out the log (`gcloud logging`) to figure out what's causing the issue.

Also you might want to check out how I [configured the authentication](https://serverfault.com/a/1141938/162443), and this [Cloud SQL authentication overview](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/d2a257ecd151d8efef32193f46db398e).