# psql: error: FATAL: Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've set up my cloud sql database using IAM authentication by following these instructions:

https://binx.io/2021/05/19/how-to-connect-to-a-cloudsql-with-iam-authentication/

I'm attempting to authenticate from a cloud compute instance. Connectivity is in place to my database:

```
gcloud sql users list --instance=db1-instance-e740ca44
NAME              HOST  TYPE                       PASSWORD_POLICY
postgres                BUILT_IN
sa-cloudsql-user        CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

IAM authentication is enabled:

```
gcloud sql instances describe db1-instance-e740ca44 --format json | jq '.settings.databaseFlags'
[
  {
    "name": "cloudsql.iam_authentication",
    "value": "on"
  }
]
```

But I'm still getting the following error when trying to connect:

```
psql "host=127.0.0.1 port=5432 sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=sa-cloudsql-user"
psql: error: FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM service account authentication failed for user "sa-cloudsql-user"
```

I've even tried granting the owner permission to both the sa-cloudsql-user service account and the service account that my compute instance runs with to ensure it's not an IAM permissions issue, but no dice.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If all of your configurations for service account authentication are correct. Can you please let me know the version of google-auth-library-oauth2-http library you are currently using.

Comment: What you're doing is called "Manual IAM Authentication" and you'll need to provide the user's OAuth2 token as the password for it to work.

Comment: Not 100% sure how to check the google-auth-library-oauth2-http library version, but I'm assuming it's the most recent as I'm blowing away this entire environment and re-installing daily. Google Cloud SDK verison 414.0.0

Comment: Sorry @enocom, I'm a little unclear on this. What step am I missing for the automatic IAM authentication? I'm doing everything described here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins#log-in-with-automatic

When I start cloud_sql_proxy with the  -enable_iam_login option, should that not be handling the automatic piece for me?

Comment: My mistake. I didn't see that you were launching the Auth proxy in your question. Adding just how you're starting it would help. Ultimately, you need to run the Auth Proxy with the same IAM principal as the user. That usually means supplying the SA's credentials to the Proxy.

Comment: @enocom to clarify, by the SA's credentials do you mean its password?

Comment: A service account key file is one option. Or running on a GCE VM and using the context's application default credentials.

Comment: You might want to check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77019869/52499).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is still relevant to you, but it was a problem for me. The CLI tool ./cloud-sql-proxy must be run with these flags:

```
--auto-iam-authn 
--credentials-file={key-file-of-your-SA}
```

Comment: This might have resolved your issue, but I don't think you could get the message without `--auto-iam-authn`. Without this switch it doesn't even try to use IAM auth. Here's how I [configured the authentication](https://serverfault.com/a/1141938/162443).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error, in my case the problem was my Cloud Run service was using a different account than the one I created for my sql cloud instance, I was only able to figure this out by looking at the Cloud Instance SQL Logs, I noticed this logline:

```
db=my_db,user=my-user-service-account@my-project-411600.iam DETAIL:  The database username "my-user-service-account@my-project-411600.iam.gserviceaccount.com" provided by the client does not match the authenticated user's email ID "593261709345-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" that was likely provided to the Cloud SQL proxy or Connector.
```

To fix this I went to my Cloud Run service and changed the service account it was using to be my-user-service-account@my-project-411600.iam